# Wordpress update published date

Tags: wordpress

when I update post published date from meta box field date it's not working. I am using **save_post** hook, but it is not working properly.
Which function is used to update post date.

My code:

```
// Update publisged date from date of launch for concept

function update_concept_post_date( $post_id ){

    if ( ! wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ){       

        $post_data = get_post($post_id);
       $date = get_post_meta($post_id, '_cmb_concept_signup_date', true);
        $updated_date = explode('-', $date);
        $new_date   =   date("Y-m-d h:i:s", mktime(0,0,0,$updated_date[1],$updated_date[2],$updated_date[0]));
      if($post_data->post_type == 'concepts'){
          $my_post = array(
              'ID'           => $post_id,
              'post_date' => $new_date
          );
          // update the post, which calls save_post again
          wp_update_post( $my_post );
      }
    }
}
add_action('save_post', 'update_concept_post_date', 10);
```

Comment: `_cmb_concept_signup_date` this is your custom meta, and what is the format of this value?

Comment: date formate of published date is (Y-m-d h:i:s).

Comment: Your date parsing section is wrong. See my answer

Answer (score 1):

You are parsing date wrong, it should be;

```
$temp = explode(' ', $date);
$updated_date = explode('-', $temp[0]);
```

First parse it by space character, and first part becomes `Y-m-d` and then parse this part by `-`.

Comment: What is the output of `var_dump($my_post)` in if condition `if($post_data->post_type == 'concepts')` ? If you provide that, I can help further

Comment: All Realted data from this post.

Comment: You said it didn't work, but how did you understand it? I need to know `$my_post` value to say something. I have tested my code on my site, and it is fully working.